# add event handler an element inside a info window google maps v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

hi I'm trying to add to button inside an info window an event i tried like this

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div></br><span class="formatText">Ubicacion del Marcador: </span>' + event.latLng.toString() 
            + '</br> <input type="button" id="btnPrueba" value="prueba"/></div>'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnPrueba'), 'click', removeMarker);
});

function removeMarker(){

    alert('it works');
}
```

What am i doing wrong? or it's another way to do this?. Thanks

**Edit**

I'm also tried with jquery like this but although the event it's get by the function the alert doesn't show.  When i do the debug with chrome it's works :(

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
    $("#btnPrueba").click(function () {

        alert('funciona');
    });
});
```

Comment: @js1568 it's not an error only doesn't works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the "onclick" attribute for the button.

```
'<input type="button" id="btnPrueba" value="prueba" onclick="removeMarker()"/>'
```

Comment: thanks good idea. And it works but it have to be a way to make this works. Also thanks for asking

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you trying to add multiple events to a single button click?

Comment: i mean adding to event handler with jquery or with listener of google maps

Comment: @Jorge Did you work out a way to add an event handler dynamically to a button in an InfoWindow? I'm currently struggling with this (using jQuery to add the click handler).

Comment: @DarrenCook The only way that I can make this work is adding the javascript code in the constuction of the infowindow

Answer (score 1):

Calling a global function like @DeeV's shown really does seem like the straightest shot at this (except for dirtying the global namespace a smidge which is looked down on these days). jQuery event delegation does work without any additional setTimeout gymnastics but feels like a heavier function call stack to accomplish the same goal. e.g.

```
$("#myMapContainer").on("click", "#btnPrueba", function() {alert "it works";});
```

However, sticking with the global approach, on top of @DeeV's answer, often the trick is getting some contextual values that you can act upon in that event handler:

- one way is embedding parameter values to the function call in the
  InfoWindow content string
- along those lines, as you generate each Marker, push
  it's reference to an array (also necessarily global) and thereby facilitate
  Marker API calls later in the handler (e.g. setIcon(), etc.)

## e.g. JS Pseudocode

```
var myMarkerArray = [];

function removeMarker(markerIndex) {
  myMarkerArray[markerIndex].setMap(null);
}

for(int i=0; i<myLocationData.length; i++) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
  myMarkerArray.push(marker);
  var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: '<input type="button" id="btnPrueba" value="prueba" onclick="removeMarker('+i+')"/>' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to use a short timeout.

```
var infoWindow = ...  (as in your question) ...
infoWindow.open(...);

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#btnPrueba').on('click', function(e){
    alert("It works at last!");
    });
  },50);  //Wait for 0.05s
```

When I didn't use the `setTimeout` wrapper it did not work. Even though `setContent()` and `open()` had already been called. I assume this means the creation is done asynchronously.

NOTE: the "50" is a magic number, so potentially brittle.

NOTE: using the following also did *not* work for me, which I still find strange and cannot explain:

```
$('#btnPrueba').on('click', document, function(e){
  alert("No luck...");
  });
```